# Python Multi-Processing and Combing DFs

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

I am reading a large data source into pandas and breaking it up into 3 chunks. I want to use multi processing so that I can complete an analysis function simultaneously for each chunk. The output after each function is a dataframe. Then I need to combine those three small dataframes.

```
#This part creates an empty dataframe with the correct column names
d = {'ID': [''], 'Title': [''],'Organization': [''], 'PI': [''],'PI_Phone': [''], 'PI_Email': [''],
     'Start_Date': [''], 'End_Date': [''],'FY': [''], 'Funding': [''], 'Abstract': [''],
     'URL': [''],'Street': [''], 'City': [''],'State': [''], 'Zip': [''],'Country': ['']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def algorithm(df):
    print('Alg Running')
    df['Abstract'] = df['Abstract'].fillna(value='Abstract')
    df['Abstract'] = df['Title'] + ' : ' + df['Abstract']
    wide_net = df[df['Abstract'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(tissue+te_abstract+temp_abstract+tx_abstract+armi_abstract+['cell ','tissue','organ ']),na=False)]
    return wide_net

def chunk1():
    print('chunk1')
    therange = 0
    df1 = pd.read_sql(('SELECT * FROM Clean_SBIR LIMIT {},1000;').format(therange), con=conn)
    return algorithm(df1)
def chunk2():
    print('chunk2')
    therange = 1000
    df2 = pd.read_sql(('SELECT * FROM Clean_SBIR LIMIT {},1000;').format(therange), con=conn)
    algorithm(df2)
def chunk3():
    print('chunk3')
    therange = 2000
    df3 = pd.read_sql(('SELECT * FROM Clean_SBIR LIMIT {},1000;').format(therange), con=conn)
    algorithm(df3)

# creating processes
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=chunk1())
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=chunk2())
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=chunk3())

# starting process 1
p1.start()
# starting process 2
p2.start()
# starting process 3
p3.start() 

#This is where I am struggling
results = pd.concat([chunk1(),chunk2(),chunk3()])

# wait until process 1 is finished 
p1.join() 
# wait until process 2 is finished 
p2.join()
# wait until process 3 is finished 
p3.join()


print('done')
```

My algorithm function returns the correct data and then chunk1 also returns the correct data, but I can't figure out how to combine them because the multiprocessing is getting in the way.

Comment: Try concatenating after all the 3 process are done.

Comment: Even if you manage to make it work, I would bet a coin that it will take more time that a single process implementation... Your current code just forget the dataframes after building them, but even it it didn't, you will end with one partial dataframe in each child process and would still have to make all of them accessible in the parent. What it the rationale for multiprocessing here?

Comment: We are working with massive data sets (some 6-8gb), this one being the smallest. We built an algorithm that goes through these datasets but for some it takes 24-48hrs to run through the algorithm. So I am just trying to figure out how we can cut down that time. I thought multi processing the chunks would be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

the above looks somewhat strange, maybe refactor something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

SQL = 'SELECT * FROM Clean_SBIR LIMIT %s, %s'

def process_data(offset, limit):
    df = pd.read_sql(SQL, conn, params=(offset, limit))
    return algorithm(df)

with Pool(3) as pool:
   jobs = []
   limit = 1000
   for offset in range(0, 3000, limit):
      jobs.append((offset, limit))
   final_df = pd.concat(pool.starmap(process_data, jobs))
```

basically you were duplicating up code unnecessarily, and not returning results from your chunk processing algorithm.

that said, you probably don't want to be doing anything like this.  all data is [`picked`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) between processes, and is part of the point @Serge was making.

Comment: If RAM is limited, would the pickling in multiprocessing actually be beneficial to free memory between tasks assuming more than just 3 would be used (or those 3 would be massive)?

Comment: I am planning to run this on my server which has 23 GB of Ram available. Would this be a smart way to use it?

Comment: you're going to temporally get four copies of the data that way, two in the child process (the real pandas dataframe, and the pickled copy) and two in the parent process (a copy of the picked data when it receives it and another while it turns into a dataframe). also note that Python objects are **much** bigger than data is on disk...

Comment: What does Pool(3) do?

Comment: the [docs are here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool), which part isn't clear?