# Can you run `pd.read_sql` in parallel or asyncronously?

Tags: sql-server, pandas, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have a function that needs to run three SQL queries to get some data and then return a calculation.

Something like:

```
df1 = pd.read_sql('''...''', cnxn) # Takes 5min
df2 = pd.read_sql('''...''', cnxn) # Takes 25min
df3 = pd.read_sql('''...''', cnxn) # Takes 20min
ans = my_calculation(df1, df2, df3)
```

Is there a way to load data into `df1`, `df2`, and `df3` in parallel? Or any other tricks to you'd recommend to improve runtime. As far as I can tell my database has capacity to run all three queries at the same time with minimal slowdown.

Comment: Try to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56940321/python-multi-processing-and-combing-dfs

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I can tell my database has capacity to run all three queries at the same time with minimal slowdown.

That's somewhat unlikely.  SQL Server supports parallel queries, so there's no obvious reason why kicking off the three queries concurrently will actually be better than running them sequentially.  Even if the SQL Server can run them in parallel, you may be bottlenecked on the the network, or on the client reading the results.

You can, of course, test this by running the queries in 3 seperate programs, and if that's actually helpful, codify the multi-process parallelism using the `multiprocessing` package to fan out to multiple processes and marshal the results back to a single process.

But the normal way to improve the query execution time is on the SQL Server, not the client.  Start by looking at the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) and/or examinging the [Session Wait Stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15),  eg

```
stats = pd.read_sql('''select * 
from sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats
where session_id = @@spid
order by wait_time_ms desc''', cnxn) # gather the session wait stats
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure my Python code is waiting to get the data for `df1` before kicking off `df2`

Comment: Thank you for your idea on Session Wait Times. Running the three queries in three separate Jupyter Notebooks results in all three finishing within 30min (vs. them taking 50min if run one after the other)