# concat 2 dataframe after using thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I tried to use thread to improve speed, but I failed when trying to concat results:

```
def join_data(SHD):
   do something here
   frames = [df1, df2]
   result1 = pd.concat(frames)
   return result1
```

This is code about threading

```
start_time = time.time()    
final_results=pd.DataFrame()
threads = [] 
#q = queue.Queue()
for dulieu in data.itertuples():# each thread could be like a new 'click'
    th = threading.Thread(target=join_data, args=(dulieu.SHD,))    
    th.start() # could `time.sleep` between 'clicks' to see whats'up without headless option
    final_results=pd.concat([final_results,result1])
    threads.append(th)
for th in threads:
    th.join() # Main thread wait for threads finish

print("multiple threads took ", (time.time() - start_time), " seconds")
```

Cannot print out final_results.

```
NameError: name 'result1' is not defined
```

result1 is returned from def join_data
final_results use concat result1
Thanks for reading

Comment: please always post the actual error message. please edit the question to include it. we don't know what `data` or `final_result` is, nor is `result1` being assigned anywhere.

Comment: I edit the question.

Comment: if you can instead use multiprocessing have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56940828/42346 for ideas.